# How to install missing arial font in TeX?

Tags: fonts, errors

I am using the basic TeX install on MacOS to compile a document and obtained this error

```
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input arial' failed to make arial.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font \pearsonkluj=arial at 9.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
l.151 \font\pearsonkluj=arial at 9pt
```

I am wondering how I can install the arial at 9.0pt font?

I googled the arial font and found https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/arial/?lang=en but I don't know if this is the right font I need, nor do I understand which folder of `/usr/local/texlive/2021basic` I should put the font file.

Comment: You'll have to give us a bit more information - are you using LaTeX or XeLaTeX? A minimum working example would also help.

Comment: @NotelessScholar I am using TeX and compiling with `pdftex` and I have been trying to render https://ctan.org/pkg/texbook?lang=en for studying purposes but keep getting errors.

Comment: Have you tried installing the urw-arial package (https://ctan.org/pkg/urw-arial) via your distributions package manager?

Comment: @NotelessScholar I used `tlmgr` but the package was not found.

Comment: You're *not* allowed to run TeX over `texbook.tex`.

Comment: @egreg really, I thought it's open source

Answer (score 0):

As @egreg said [in the comments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635713/how-to-install-missing-fonts#comment1584465_635713), you're not supposed to run `tex texbook` or `pdftex texbook`.  Therefore, please DON'T replace `arial` by any of its freely available alternatives, such as `ua1r8r`, and DON'T comment out the offending lines as follows:

```
%\font\pearsonkluj=arial at 9pt
%\leftline{\pearsonkluj ScoutAutomatedPrintCode}
```

Never ever do this. Don't evade copyright!